# Converting data from Mongo to MySQL (110M docs, 60Gigs) - Tips and Suggestions?

Tags: c#, mysql, mongodb, windows-server-2008, mongodb-.net-driver

I have been tasked with porting data from a MongoDB database to a MySQL database.
(There are strong reasons for porting - so it *has* to be done).

The MongoDB collection:

- Has approx 110 Million documents
- Weighs 60 GB in size
- Has indexes for important properties
- Is running of a Windows 2008 standalone separate server which is not serving any production traffic

The Setup that we have tried:

- An Large Amazon EC2 Win2008 Server instance with 7.5 Gigs of RAM / 8 Gigs of Page File
- A C# console app which converts the MongoDB data to a local MySQL database

We pick up 1K documents at a time in memory from the MongoDB, do the necessary processing and then save them to the MySQL db doing batch writes of 500 at a time.

The problem that we are facing is that every 2.5 M docs, the server chokes up and Mongo responds very slowly - timing out the app's data fetch operation (Free RAM gets over by the time 1M documents are processed)

We are moving ahead slowly by killing the mongod process and starting it again every 2.5M records when it crashes - but I bet we're doing something wrong.

**Question:**

Should I move the Mongo Server to a Linux based Large Instance and MySQL to the Amazon RDS for this and rewrite the conversion app in PHP? Will it help?

The reason we decided to keep it all on one box was the latency issue of having different servers on different boxes - but I guess that is moot if the box is choking up.

What other things can I try / tips I can use?

Thanks for reading this far!

**-- Update 01 --**

Its been approximate 6 hours since I restarted my app and have made the following change:

1. Increased Mongo Read count from 1,000 to 10,000 records at a time. .skip(10K).limit(10K)
2. Removed all indexes from the MySQL target database.
3. Increased the Windows page size from 4 Gigs to 8 Gigs

My memory is at 100% consumption but the app is running still. (Last time it croaked in 52 mins). Mongo eating 6.8 Gigs of RAM, MySQL - 450 Megs and the converter app - 400 Megs (approx values).

Processed 11M records so far - but the speed has gone down to 370 records / sec from approx 500 records / sec.

Next steps are going to be to isolate both the Mongo and MySQL servers to separate boxes and - keeping all of them in the same Amazon availability zone to minimize latency.

**-- Update 02 --**

We made some changes in code to use the Mongo Cursor and letting it auto increment automatically as against doing a .skip().limt() ourselves. This greatly sped up the process and we were doing 1250 records per second from 300 odd earlier. However, the application started consuming too much memory and would run out of RAM and crash and needed to be restarted after every 2M records.

We used this code snippet:

```
var docs = db[collectionName].Find(query);
docs.SetBatchSize(numOfResultsToFetchAtATime);
foreach (var d in docs) {
  // do processing
}
```

So what this does is fetch 'numOfResultsToFetchAtATime' records at a time - but then progresses automatically in the loop and fetches the next set of records. Mongo takes care of this progression using a Cursor and hence it is a lot faster.

However, we have still not been able to successfully port this.
Will post my reply with code when that happens properly.

**-- Update 03: Success --**

We finally used @scarpacci's suggestion of doing a mongoexport.
Do remember that it is essential that the mongodb is on a linux box and not a windows box.

We first tried doing a mongoexport from Windows on the local MongoDB and no matter what we tried, it would fail at different places for one large collection (13Gigs+)

Finally, I restored the DB on a Linux box and mongoexport worked like a charm.

There is no Json -> MySQL converter - so that much we had to do.
With a little tweaking, we were able to use our previous app and read the files and write to MySQL directly. It was quick and relatively error free.

We had some issues with the large files, but breaking down the 13GB file to 500 Meg long files helped with that and we were able to migrate all data to MySQL successfully.

Many thanks to everyone for spending time helping us out. Hope that this explanation helps someone in the future.

Comment: What about indexes, is it all right?

Comment: I think moving the app and the mysql to a different server would probably help. Mongo likes to be left alone, so it can consume all available RAM. You might consider dropping your indexes if they aren't being used in the migration. Alternatively, you can try to configure mysql to have a very low max RAM, and make sure the C# app isn't growing its memory usage.

Comment: Why are you switching to MySql? Just curious....would like to know the reasoning /issues with MongoDB...thanks --S

Comment: I haven't used MongoDB and it's been years since I've used MySQL, but, I'm gonna go out on a limb and point the finger at your console app. I've made C# console apps before to do the same thing, with smaller amounts of records (thousands, not millions). I've always seen the console app grow[ in memory] as it fetched data. I didn't care because it was done soon after anyway, but you may want to invest in rewriting the console app and **ABSOLUTELY MAKING SURE** you're cleaning up it's memory usage as it's performing its tasks.

Comment: @scarpacci: This is an analytics database and the earlier developer chose to do it on Mongo as at that time, the data wasn't very important. A kind of a quick fire and dirty approach. Suddenly our app (its an iPhone app) took off and we have this mountain of data which is not query-able easily. Indexes no longer helping much and map-reducers take a decent amount of time for the reports that we need. So, we are making the plunge and moving data to a completely de-normalized (no foreign keys) MySQL instance.

Comment: @saurabhj sounds like you already have a plan which based on your reporting needs makes sense.  You might want to look at sharding the data ands scaling out your instances. Then see if you can use your map/reducers to populate a separate MySQL instance that could be used strictly for reporting.  Good luck...post your outcome if you would!

Comment: @saurabhj Am I missing something? Moving from Mongo back to RDBMS?
So why MongoDB is so favorized? Was it misused or just MySQL for that particular scenario is much better? What about scaling horizontally?

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue basically we were using Mongo incorrectly. Data was required for analytics and some folks needed to be able to run SQL queries directly on the DB. The previous team that implemented the solution in Mongo did not realise how large the DB / project would turn out to be. Hence it was just a case of bad-use-case for us. We ended up logically breaking down data into different tables - which made it possible to query quickly using SQL. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [mongoexport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport) then performing some sort of Bulk Insert into MySQl? Not sure if that is available in MySql, but we perform something similar in SQL Server all the time. Might make the dumps / inserts easier to break apart and optimize? Just a thought....

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My last option is to do the export to json and try to push into MySQL by reading the json files. But getting out 60 gigs of textual data and processing those many files have their own logistical challenges. So I have kept this as a last resource.

Comment: This finally worked for us - the other things we tried were either too buggy or took a lot of time. We finally did a mongoexport and wrote an app to read the file and update MySQL which surely worked - and pretty quickly as well!

Answer (score 3):

I had issues migrating data to SQLServer using .NET once - even though I tried to keep it as lightweight as possible it was still unacceptable slow. In the end I wrote a quick C++ OLEDB app and things went significantly faster. I'm still trying to figure out what I did wrong in my .NET app, but it's possible the problem is in .NET. I wouldn't rewrite the conversion in PHP, but go with the performance option and use C++ (grab a tutorial off the web, its not that hard, not for a throwaway app)

So, that's one thing to look at first - as well as profile your C# app to see if it has a memory leak bug that's slowly bringing the rest of the system to a crawl.

I find it interesting you stop the MongoDB app instead of anything else. What makes you think its MongoDB that is dying, and not the other systems? If its memory usage, then splitting to separate boxes might make a difference, if its slowly growing memory, then read fewer chunks - Mongo should be fine with reading data, so if its not, chances are its something you've done to it to make it hold on to its memory, either in configuration or in your app.

Fire up perfmon and look at the memory, swap, disk IO and CPU usages of Mongo, your app and MySQL instance.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling if the app or mysql were killed, it would probably keep it running for a bit, also. More info about memory profiles of the different processes would be good.

Comment: I agree, using managed code to perform a migration like this may be (most likely is) chewing up substantially more resources than are really necessary. C++ is definitely a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I had written some PHP code a while ago on the same config Linux system - and Mongo showed similar behaviour. When I was fetching data - for the initial 300K records or so, I was doing 1000 records per second (approx) before it started exponentially slowing down. On Windows, I chose to restart Mongo as the mongod process had grown from using 350 Megs of RAM when it started to 6.5 Gigs in 6 hours. (the .Net app is currently using 400 Megs). Will post more updates as I try new stuff... Will try and give the C++ option a whirl.

Comment: @saurabhj : 6.5 gig of RAM, that'd do it :) Now, I know MongoDB is used in many areas and you'd think that if it stopped after a few thousand reads someone would have noticed... so I now suspect your app, is it holding onto something in Mongo that should be released? Perhaps you should send this question to 10gen, apparently their support is top-notch.

Comment: Mongo will do that if it is not competing for resources, due to the nature of memory mapped files. The trouble comes (in my experience) when it isn't competing for resources, and then suddenly it is--it's the OS's job to release that file cache so other processes can use it. How big are your indexes in mongo?

Answer (score 3):

Once I migrated a big database (not 60 GB, but big enough to show issues)
I ended up writing a small app doing the job.

That way, i read from one DB and wrote to another, with some kind of 
batch mode (I was facing similar problems with database crashes etc)

What I have done was spawning smaller transactions for each part
and closing them every time a work item was solved.

We had tables in both databases, no documents, but the problem will
be the same.

After all:

- There is one application that coordinates the migration, but not having any database connections on it's own
- Multiple instances spawned from the coordination app to move the data, doing a work item, closing afterwards (have some way of reporting success before closing) That way you can have multiple readers / writers and can experiment with the count, I had only about 10 concurrent reader / writer instances at one time. If your documents are small enough, you can spawn lots more. But they will close very fast anyway.

**Note:** Do not have indexes in the target database while writing to
it will give you an ultimate performance boost. Set the indexes 
up when you have all data in them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason for you to be writing the data directly to MySQL - split the job into 2 separate stages and you'll be running first MongoDB and then MySQL so they will not compete for resources - it looks like the growing MySQL process starves Mongo on RAM or io.

Stage one: get data from MongoDB, process it and save it to a text file (as SQL). Stop Mongo, start MySQL

Stage two: run regular database import using file generated in stage 1.

Comment: better yet, combine two of the answers: use mongoexport to dump out data from mongo, use some sort of load into mySQL and only write a program which converts JSON file to SQL insert statements file.

Comment: Yes. Doing the Mongo -> json text files -> MySQL is my last and final option which I am pretty sure will work. But I think that will take a lot of time. If nothing else works, I will definitely go that route. Thanks for validating my thought process. :)

Comment: And that's where you are mistaken. It will be faster. With MySQL and Mongo competing for resources (especially IO) the actual performance will degrade big time. If you run both at the same time don't expect each to be running at ~50% of the speed they get alone. 5-10% is more realistic. By running operations on MySQL first and then on Mongo you might actually do it 2-3 times faster. I have learned it the hard way.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that restarting MongoDB fixes the performance issue and the consistent number of records you can process before it crops up sounds like a resource leak to me.  I'd make sure everything's getting closed, etc.  Make sure MySQL isn't configured to use too much memory, or better, move it to another machine.

Comment: MySQL is behaving very nicely and consuming only 450 Megs of RAM at this stage (6 hours of running). Mongo is actually eating up 6.78 Gigs of RAM. I am guessing running Mongo on Windows might be a bad idea and my next step might be to actually run this on a Linux box in a separate machine. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You can take a look at the memory and swapping before you restart MongoDB.  Ballooning memory usage and disk swapping would be symptoms of a resource leak.